# WebKit assertion "Error" after dismissing ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, webkit, wkwebview

So I have a XIB file with some views and a WKWebView.

This file is linked to a UIViewController class.

Everything works fine, all the functionalities work. However, upon dismissing the ViewController I get these errors:

```
2022-03-12 14:19:18.380104+0100 Example[13697:342765] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2022-03-12 14:19:18.380401+0100 Example[13697:342765] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1084ea780 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'GPUProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=13705, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
2022-03-12 14:19:18.390251+0100 Example[13697:342765] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2022-03-12 14:19:18.390709+0100 Example[13697:342765] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1084fe120 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=13702, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
2022-03-12 14:19:48.280532+0100 Example[13697:342532] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2022-03-12 14:21:29.545076+0100 Example[13697:344267] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2022-03-12 14:21:29.545356+0100 Example[13697:344267] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1084fe2a0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=13721, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
2022-03-12 14:21:29.562582+0100 Example[13697:344267] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2022-03-12 14:21:29.562851+0100 Example[13697:344267] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1084fe360 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=13721, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
2022-03-12 14:21:59.476480+0100 Example[13697:342532] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

The app keeps running normally, so no fatal exception.

To me, it looks like since the WebView is initialised and linked inside the ViewController, it's deallocated on the latter's dismissal. But my guess is that this is the correct behaviour.

But it looks like something is trying to call the WKWebView after it's deallocated and I don't know what that is.

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening here @Ryuga Law? I'm having the same error

Comment: I didn't figure it out yet. And I'm not trying now as I'm working on a different task. But I'm suspecting it may be a problem with Signing and Capabilities not working correctly. Do you have an Apple ID and a Team assigned in your project? If not, try assigning that may fix the issue. Please keep me updated